# What is the ⎋ key?

Tags: macos, keyboard

This tip just popped up in my phpStorm IDE (OS X):

> The ⎋ key in any tool window moves the focus to the editor. ⇧⎋ moves
>   the focus to the editor and also hides the current (or last active)
>   tool window. The F12 key moves the focus from the editor to the last
>   focused tool window.

I've never seen that key symbol before and Google returned nothing.

Anybody know the meaning of this mysterious key?

Comment: http://www.osxkeyboardshortcuts.com/keyboard-symbols.html

Answer (score 50, accepted):

<kbd>⎋</kbd> is another symbol for the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. Like on other keyboards, on a Mac keyboard it's the key left of <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Comment: That's Apple for you: breaking tradition to get a more culturally neutral iconography (i.e it means "escape" without be spelled as abbreviated English). Again.

Comment: It's not just comparable to Escape, it *is* Escape. ⎋ is merely the symbol for Escape the same way ⇧ is the symbol for Shift.

Comment: What key is this on the touch bar MacBook Pros?

Comment: "it's the key left of F1" makes the answer complete, however this is just hilarious.

Comment: @evolutionxbox On the touchbar, it's labeled "esc". Yay consistency!

Comment: @TarkaDaal, lol, I know right!

Comment: Rotfl, they created touchbar yet called it ESC instead of ⎋ ;d